# django - handle image -

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django, and i'm having difficulties understanding how image file handling works.

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})
```

this is an exemple from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/ 
How should handle_uploaded_file() function be if i want to handle the image for size and storage??
Thanks

Comment: Well, this is not something that 1 answer can fix. Please read the docs.

Comment: you want to store the size of the image , as well as image?

Comment: Actually i want to resize the image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
import Image
def handle_uploaded_file(file):
 myimg = Image.open(file)
 myimg = myimg.resize((1024,1024),Image.ANTIALIAS)
 myimg.save('/home/arpit/myimg.png')
 #... rest of the code
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
THats what i was looking for, something like that.